# Binance futures API to retrieve filled order as signal

Tags: python, binance

i'm trying to get a live trade data feeds from binance futures via python. I'm able to send orders to binance but i would like to receive a signal if the orders been filled so i can set my stop loss, anyone can guide me in the right direction?

I've tried **request_client.start_user_data_stream()** which returns a **listenkey**, but i'm not sure what i should do with it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a `!userData` stream. If an order gets filled its pushed to you immediatly.

Here is a lib and an example file to solve this:
https://github.com/oliver-zehentleitner/unicorn-binance-websocket-api/blob/master/example_binance_futures.py